# Using two different stored procedures to insert/select with ListView

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, listview, stored-procedures

I have a ListView that is calling a stored procedure

```
create procedure GetTicketJob
    @JobID      int
as
select JobID, TicketNum, UnitID, TicketDate, ChargeToCu, RecievedToCu, DeliverToCu, 
       DeliveredToLSD, ChargedToLSD, RecievedFromLSD, P.ProductName,
       ProductVolume, Subtotal, GST, Total, PreJobNotes, JobDesc
    from Tickets T
full outer join Products P
    on T.ProductID = P.ProductID
where JobID=@JobID
go
```

This is working as expected. What my issue is, is when I try to insert using the built in insert template. I call a different stored procedure that should be inserting into the same table:

```
create proc InsertTicketJob
    @JobID              int,
    @TicketNum          int,
    @UnitID             nvarchar(5),
    @TicketDate         datetime,
    @ChargeToCu         int,
    @RecievedToCu       int,
    @DelieverToCu       int,
    @DeliveredToLSD     nvarchar(30),
    @ChargedToLSD       nvarchar(30),
    @RecievedFromLSD    nvarchar(30),
    @ProductName        nvarchar(50),
    @ProductVolume      int,
    @Subtotal           int,
    @GST                int,
    @Total              int,
    @PreJobNotes        nvarchar(300),
    @JobDesc            nvarchar(300)
as
insert into Tickets
values(@TicketNum, @JobID, @TicketDate, @ChargeToCu, @RecievedToCu, @DelieverToCu, @DeliveredToLSD, @ChargedToLSD,
   @RecievedFromLSD, @ProductVolume, (select ProductID
                                      from Products
                                      where ProductName=@ProductName), @Subtotal, @GST, @Total,      @PreJobNotes, @JobDesc, @UnitID)
go
```

When I try to do this I get the error:
`"Procedure or function InsertTicketJob has too many arguments specified."`

From my understanding I am not calling to many parameters. I have the same amount specified in the ListView, and in SQL

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick: using SELECT * / omit the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO. in your Insert Statement.. Kindly specify the fields/columns in your Insert. This is to make sure that you inserted the right number of data on the right fields. 
This will also avoid your error.

example:

```
Insert Into Table1 (Name, Address, ZipCode) Values (@Name, @Address, @Zipcode)
```